# jQuery UI Datepicker restricted AND changeable date range that auto updates

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datepicker, uidatepicker

I'm trying to get my datepicker (jQuery UI Datepicker), which has one field for "check-in" and another for "check-out" to update the check-out date based on the minimum period (in seconds) pulled in via ajax when the user chooses a check-in date, but to also allow choices to be changed.

For example I want to check-in on January 1, so the check-out field updates to January 31 based on the minimum 2592000 seconds (30 days) pulled in via ajax. But then I change my mind and decide to check-in on December 31 instead, so it should let me change the check-in date to an earlier one, and update the check-out to January 30 automatically.

Below is my code with the commented out bit that almost achieves what I want except it doesn't allow changes to earlier dates, and I'm not sure how to restrict the check-out date to the minimum period from check-in. The data pulled in via ajax also has the periods of availability so the calendar shows available days as selectable, and already booked days as not selectable. This part works fine. Any suggestions for the part that doesn't?

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/ping/availability.php",
        data: "pid="+$('#pid').text(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(calendarEvents){
            var dates = $("#checkin, #checkout").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                /*onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
                    var option = this.id == "checkin" ? "minDate" : "maxDate";
                    var instance = $(this).data("datepicker");
                    var date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
                    dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
                },*/
                dateFormat: 'M d, yy',
                beforeShowDay: function (date){
                    for (i = 0; i < calendarEvents.length; i++) {
                        var b,e,c;
                        b = Date.parse(calendarEvents[i]['from']);
                        e = Date.parse(calendarEvents[i]['to']);
                        c = Date.parse(date);
                        if((c <= e && c >= b)) {
                            return [true,"ui-state-notbooked"];
                        }
                    }
                    return [false, "ui-state-booked"];//disable all other days
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Example ajax data showing available period and min booking length in seconds:

```
[{"from":"Tue, 01 Feb 2011 00:00:00 -0800","to":"Fri, 30 Sep 2011 00:00:00 -0700","min":7776000}]
```

Comment: There has to be something missing in the code you've shared. I can't replicate the functionality you say is working now. When i pick a date from the checkin box it doesn't seem to affect the 2nd select box at all.

Comment: Ok, it appears to limit the min selection of the 2nd select box but it doesn't appear to set the value of it.

Comment: My bad, I had an illogical requirement in my writeup above. There is no need for the checkout date to always be updated to 30 days from cehckin. The requirement should only be that the checkout be a *minimum* of 30 days from checkin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/generalhenry/LerRw/2/

I think I have it working

Comment: I think yours has the same problem the author described. If you select a checking date then re-select a checkin-date prior to the first date it doesn't update the checkout date.

Comment: This one gets the points for being first to respond, getting other users' votes and not breaking anything that was already ok in my code, namely the beforeShowDay function. Thanks everyone. I need to stop assuming that UI-Datepicker has built-in capabilities it doesn't have. I could have devised this type of solution, but assumed that if datepicker could restrict ranges there was a built-in way chosen ranges could be updated without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

Does this get you any closer to what you want?

http://jsbin.com/eramu5

#### UPDATED

I've updated my script so that you can have a minimum of 1 month. And you can set the dates in the checkin and the checkout date pickers.

http://jsbin.com/ihufi5

#### [Here's a video explaining how my script works](http://screenr.com/PbZ)